# bootstrap3 collapsed navbar issue with navbar-header that overflows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K22Nh/). The issue is when the navigation bar is collapsed the layout is pretty messed up (to reproduce just shrink the window size to the size of an iPhone). I believe this is because of the navbar-header that I've put on the following stays constantly on the left and there's no spacing for the collapsed navbar:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand nav-title-logo" href="http://dev.shopious.com/">  </a>

       </div>
```

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Sorry. I dont understand what is going on. When collapsed is looks fine! http://screencloud.net/v/wSsu

Comment: @nahtnam the issue is when you open the collapsed menu

Comment: Ok, here is what I see http://screencloud.net/v/rkaS What is the issue?

Comment: You're using desktop styles on the logo. Design your logo in min-width media queries for desktop and put, outside those media queries, the style for the logo on mobile.

Comment: @nahtnam make it even smaller than that, width of 320

Comment: @ChristinaArasmoBeymer can you give me an example

Comment: @adit i checked out the jsfiddle on my iphone and here are some screenshots of how it looks. This is when I first visit the page http://imgur.com/LOwRcf3 . This is as I zoom in. http://imgur.com/RZaMnlM

Answer (score 1):

see also: [Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo/18475817)

you will have to set the height of your navbar / navbar header according the height of your brand logo:

```
@media (max-width:767px) 
{
    .navbar, .navbar-header{height: 83px;}
}
```

Note setting the height to 100% won't work here cause you also use:

```
.navbar-default {
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #e06b55;
}
```

Setting the height to 44px seems to break your layout.

You also don't need:

```
.nav-collapse > .nav:first-child {
    left: 135px;
}
```

In your fiddle you use: `navbar-collapse in` where i expect `collapse navbar-collapse`