# Menu items not clearing logo in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm in the process of updating my company's website from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3 and have what I assume is a relatively simply issue to resolve; the menu items are not clearing the logo in the navbar.  Pulling the menu items to the right does not seem to resolve the issue, as when the menu collapses the items are still to the right.

Here is the link to the [site](http://www.accomplicated.ca/webdesign/TSP-3/) in development.

Here is the code for the nav:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top wrapper" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/tsp-logo.png" class="logo img-responsive" alt="Third Sector Publishing" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html#about"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> About</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Team</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="scroll"><a href="#cww">Canadian Who's Who</a></li>
              <li class="scroll"><a href="#cdg">Canadian Donor's Guide</a></li>
              <li class="scroll"><a href="#cc">CharityCAN</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> should be <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

Comment: Nope, that won't fix it. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18475817/1004312

Comment: I posted an answer below with the sample
 
http://jsbin.com/OtamALu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### http://jsbin.com/OtamALu/1/

You want the logo to not knock into the navigation.

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.accomplicated.ca/webdesign/TSP-3/img/tsp-logo.png" class="logo img-responsive" alt="Third Sector Publishing" /></a>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html#about"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> About</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Team</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#cww">Canadian Who's Who</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#cdg">Canadian Donor's Guide</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#cc">CharityCAN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
  .logo {padding-right:80px;min-with:200px;}
  .logo-wrapper {max-width:400px;padding-top:8px}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You've been extremely helpful.

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to tweak it. Generally, I make the image itself no larger than the largest size on desktop and then add the padding and stuff so it won't hit it. Actually, I don't use images for logos, I use svg since retina makes images blurry.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the `position:absolute` on `.logo`
on line 76 of your `style.css` stylesheet.

Comment: +1 indeed this is also another case, if it is required to reposition the logo i would suggest `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

It is required to add something like,

```
.navbar-brand {
  width: 386px;/*width of the logo image*/
}
```

In order for the `navbar-brand` link to occupy the necessary space.

Answer (score 0):

on line 7 of bootstrap.min.css you need to add this css style on this class
`.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {float: right; margin: 0 14px 0 0;}`

OR you can add this class name on navbar `"pull-right"` which has been already defined on the bootstrap css