# static horizontal navigation bar in bootstrap overlaps content area

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.I have a logo image(instead of project name) and a horizontal navigation bar on top of my page.Logo image is on the left side.When  browser window is reduced navigation bar shrinks.
I have 2 problems:

(a)The menu that comes as drop down(when window size is reduced) overlaps the content area
(b)Menu comes below the logo image.The logo image is about 160px.(I think i may have to reduce the logo image size when window size is reduced).Can anyone tel me how to reduce image size or any other method to solve this!!

Comment: can you paste the code im bootply or jsfiddle ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Logo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo)

Comment: i tried the link..but doesnt solve ma problem...this is ma navigation bar code...        http://pastebin.com/507AbyKB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If reducing the image size in steps is going to solve your problem, then you could use media queries in your CSS to achieve this. For example-

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
/* Reduce image size */
}
```

For a detailed description of media queries, check http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ or http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries