# Cannot add svg logo to navbar using angular-strap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

Basing on the [documentation](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/navbars), I've created a simple navbar with image instead of text for "brand". However, my .svg image isn't visible. Why?

SSCCE: http://plnkr.co/edit/bb2bBv0dD67fFBSpS5uH

Solution from [->THIS<-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo?rq=1) question doesn't work.

Since all code from plnkr have to be accomapanied by code, let me paste(probably) the most crucial part:

Toggle navigation

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-dropdown="networks_dropdown">
                                            Networks
                                    </button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#">Workplace</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">Generate</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">Export</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">Training</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there but the parent element doesn't seem to have any width..if you add that the logo appears

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 50px; /* see here */
}
```