# Bootstrap navbar-toggle is not at the top

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have this issue, I'm trying to get the navbar-toggle to get up into the corner but it's over lapping.

[image]

I also have a icon in pc view that over lapping which I really like.
[image]

Is there a way to fix the navbar-toggle??

My code is below.

```
   <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <img class="visible-xs img-rounded pull-right" src="smallicon2.png" alt="" > 

    <div class="container">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

        <div class="navbar-brand  page-scroll">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

                    <img src="icon2.png" class="img-rounded hidden-xs"  />


        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>


                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap CSS, Following causing the issue `padding: 15px;`

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

This may fix the issue `padding: 0px 15px;` but it will effect the logo too

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjs73act/)

Proper Fix without effecting the logo, change `margin-top: 8px;` to `margin-top: -5px;` to following CSS in bootstrap css file

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: -5px; <<<< Here
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjs73act/1/)

Note: Better approach do not edit bootstrap css, make customstyle.css and add above css with `!important` rule in custom css.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't waste your time with fixing. Copy and paste the complete navbar from [Bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). After that, delete HTML you don't need, correctly!
2. The problem often begins if you want to have a navbar with a bigger logo.
   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo/30448647#30448647) is a precise instruction how to create a Bootstrap navbar with a bigger logo.