# Bootstrap 3 navbar image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3, I am trying to add an image to the `navbar-header` but it's not visible unless it's a link to an external online image.  It won't show if it's loaded from the local image folder.

In the example below, the first image is visible but the second is not.  The second/local image is the same exact image as the first one.

I can verify that the local path image is being loaded by inspecting the loaded page with IE developer tools.  It's just not showing.

```
<div class="navbar-header">                
    <!-- This one is visible --> 
    <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="https://sp.yimg.com/xj/th?id=OIP.M55851906bcec8ef3ef5a99872e29a565o0&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300"></a> 

     <!-- This one is not visible -->
     <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="img/thG1UAD6R0.jpg"></a>

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

I've used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo) as a resource but it doesn't help much. I can't find much on why a live url image would be visible and a local image path wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried look the folder permission.
I had that kind of problem when I put my images in a folder that was just to write not to read.