# Fitting an SVG logo in Bootstrap navbar with brand text on right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm trying to have my svg logo floating left inside the navbar, then the brand text ("Oishii") next to it (not under) and then my links on the right side.
I need them to be all aligned and centered vertically.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo) for the logo part but since my logo is svg, I have to put it inside div or else it overflows and I also want text right next to it.
I know I can technically just make one svg with the text in it but I'd rather real text since I've heard you should minimize actual text in your logos (selectable, searchable, etc).

```css
.navbar {
    border: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    letter-spacing: 4px;

}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px; /* firefox bug fix */
  width: auto;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.navbar-header h1 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: black !important;
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar {
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: all 0.6s 0s;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </button>
            <div class"navbar-left"><img src="oishiilogo.svg"></div>
            <h1 class="brand brand-name navbar-left">Oishii</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Reserve</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've put my code [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/linhlekim/pen/QKVgbm?editors=1010) as well for you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.logo` class to the div wrapping the image, then add this css

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 52px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

For the mobile view you will have to use media queries & change the logo & brand name to `display: inline-block;` & add margin etc

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for replying! It still doesn't seem to work after I added the logo class and logo defined as above for css. I updated my codepen with your suggestion and it doesn't budge ( I tested for desktop only for now)

Comment: Still missing the = on codepen, should be <div class="navbar-left logo">

Comment: Oh! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much! It works!