# add logo image to bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I used the prescribed method from bootstrap docs

```
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/img/hangers.jpg" alt="" width="30" height="24">
        </a>
      </div>
```

but the image doesn't display
[image]

And Yes, I linked the path correctly. I checked like 50 times already.

Here is the directory structure
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo)

Comment: Could you please show us your directory structure so we can better help?

Comment: @Billions.A.Joel I've posted the structure. Have a look at it

Comment: try to put a dot at start

Comment: please reply if that worked or not. Then I will start viewing the problem with a new perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a dot before the source of the image file.
[image]
**Results**

[image]

I think. You are not able to pick up photo from your system as code works fine run snippet below:

```html
<div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTW6509Xrnys2Pp_8RB3ffNOsqDrKlPtkvkRQ&usqp=CAU" alt="" width="30" height="24">
</a>
</div>
```